# Russian encoding with utf8 phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, phpmyadmin

I have this xml file to parse:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Exchange_Rates>
      <Actual_Rates>
        <Bank>
          <Name>АКРОПОЛЬ</Name>
          <Url>http://bank...</Url>
        </Bank>
      </Actual_Rates>
    </Exchange_Rates>
```

I parsed it in to a database, everything worked just fine, I could read and write the name of the bank with mysql database correctly in Russian (АКРОПОЛЬ).
But the problem was in the phpMyAdmin, I couldn't edit database with phpMyAdmin because the name wasn't showed correctly.(ÐÐšÐ ÐžÐŸÐžÐ›Ð¬)
I had set up the colation in both database and table to utf8_general_ci.
Any helps?

Comment: What's in phpMyAdmin's `config.inc.php` at `$cfg['DefaultCharset']`?

Comment: I have no line like that. So how to config it as well?

Comment: What happens if you tell your browser to override the page's character encoding and select UTF-8?

Comment: In addition to what @Mike says, what happens if you set `$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf-8';` to `config.inc.php`?

Comment: Thank you, but $cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf-8'; not works, and overriding the page's charater encoding either

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4813043/4421474

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: `DefaultCharset` hasn't been a configuration option in phpMyAdmin since 2010 (so it was probably removed with version 3.4.0), so unless you've got a very old and unsupported version that's not going to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[German Umlaute in Mysql/Phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053258/german-umlaute-in-mysql-phpmyadmin)
This worked for me

> I struggled with the same problem for a long time. Run this query as
>   soon as you connect to the database and your web application will
>   display characters as they appear in phpmyadmin:
>
> SET NAMES 'utf8'
>
> For some reason MySQL is set up on my systems to assume input and
>   output are encoded as latin1, which means when I send it utf8 input it
>   stores it in the database incorrectly, but because the conversion is
>   reversed for output, the mess is undone and it displays correctly in
>   the browser (except when using phpmyadmin, which displays it
>   faithfully). This is only true when the conversion results in
>   characters that are permitted by the character set used in the
>   database field where it is stored, so you can get errors unless you
>   stop this conversion from happening with the above query.